# How to trim video clip and convert to byte array at runtime?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, video-player

My Video Player plays clips from a path at runtime

```
videoplayer.url = path; //mobile gallery path
videoplayer.Play();
```

I want to take this clip, trim it to 3 seconds, and convert the trimmed video to a byte array.
Is it possible?
*If so, is it also possible to change the video format while saving?

Thanks

Comment: Is your video on that URL a stream or an actual video file?

Comment: Actual video file (mobile Gallery), I can play it no problem

Comment: Is it not possible to do this by unity native tools, but you can write your own plugin for editing video, for example for iOS you can use this solution - https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Android and Ios